# Does the Fireball from Kiss of Mephistopheles cast at the same level as other spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, eldritch-invocations

*[Unearthed Arcana: Revised Class Options](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/June5UA_RevisedClassOptv1.pdf)* shows the Eldritch Invocation named **Kiss of Mephistopheles**:

> *Prerequisite: 5th level, eldritch blast cantrip*
>
> When you hit a creature with your eldritch blast, you can  cast fireball as a bonus action using a warlock spell slot. The spell must be centered on the creature you hit with eldritch blast.

My warlock is level 12, meaning all her spells slots are of 5th level.

**QUESTION**

By RAW, would the triggered fireball in this case also be cast at 5th level?

---

Related:

- [Does the UA warlock invocation Kiss of Mephistopheles require you to know the Fireball spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94815/does-the-ua-warlock-invocation-kiss-of-mephistopheles-require-you-to-know-the-fi)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes, because you use one of your spell slots to cast fireball.

As mentioned, the warlock table shows that at class level 12 your spell slots are of 5th level. The invocation states you can cast *[fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball)* using one of your spell slots:

> When you hit a creature with your eldritch blast, you can cast fireball as a bonus action **using a warlock spell slot.**

Following the text that comes with the table (emphasis mine):

> **Spell Slots**
>
> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your warlock spells of 1st through 5th level. **The table also shows what the level of those slots is;** all of your spell slots are the same level.

If you cast fireball using one of those spell slots, the fireball would be cast at 5th level too.

Comment: The invocation does not say you use a spell slot to cast this spell. It sounds logical, but some other class options allows classes like monk, that doesn't even have spell slots, to cast spells. Thus, I don't think your interpretation should be treated as obvious truth.

Comment: @Mołot The invocations says "you can cast fireball as a bonus action **using a warlock spell slot*. To be noted is that this invocation stayed in the UA and did not make it be ni published material...

Comment: @Mołot It does mention it actually. Added the relevant clause for extra clarity.